# Usar PHP WebSocket Ratchet online

Tags: php, websocket

Estou tentando usar o [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) para criar `WebSockets` em `PHP` em um site que possuo. Quando fiz os testes (`localhost`) tudo funcionou perfeitamente, mas quando tento colocar online, ele não executa a conexão. Lendo mais a respeito do assunto, vi que seria necessário mudar o `ip` para ser o do servidor - ou usar a referência correta. O que me levou a este código final:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://meusite.com.br:8000');
```

Porém quando acesso o site, após um certo tempo, recebo essa mensagem:

> failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

O arquivo de servidor ficou com este código:

```
require __DIR__ .'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ), 2000, '0.0.0.0'
);
$server->run();
```

Estou utilizando `composer` também para o gerenciamento do pacote `Ratchet`.

Não sei o que pode estar acontecendo para não haver a conexão ou o que deixei passar, mas este processo não está funcionando online, somente em `localhost`.

---

Editando a pergunta, e já adicionando a resposta ao comentário, eu possuo acesso `SSH` sim, inclusive quando tento iniciar o script conforme feito em `localhost`

```
php bin/server.php
```

O `SSH` apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Class 'Ratchet\http\HttpServer' not found in /bin/server.php on line 10

---

**Nota**: A aplicação final não vai ser um chat, estou fazendo assim apenas por estar seguindo um tutorial. O objetivo é que apenas haja a troca de mensagens para informar que um novo pedido foi feito, ou que chegou uma nova ordem de serviço, etc...

Comment: Mas você tem acesso SSH ao teu servidor pra disparar a aplicação, ou tem algum sistema de webapp pra configurar um PHP como aplicação? O websocket não roda diretamente no Apache ou Ngnix, ele é independente, não irá funcionar se acessar via `http://site/script.php`, a não ser que use o `exec();`, no entanto tenho quase certeza que será necessário privilégio pra iniciar o WebSocket.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento havia esquecido desta etapa, editei a pergunta. Mas sim, eu possuo acesso e tentei a inicialização conforme feito em localhost, mas ainda assim ele apresenta um erro.

Comment: Rodou o `composer update`? Me diz uma coisa o correto não seria isto `require __DIR__ .'/vendor/autoload.php';`? Coloca a estrutura das pastas

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Acredito que o require seja como está, pois partindo da raiz possuo 2 pastas `bin/server.php` e `vendor/autoload.php`. Dentro do vendor também existem outras pastas como a do proprio Ratchet, composer, etc.. Mas eu não rodei o composer update não, e quando tentei isso agora, apresentou erro informando que não havia permissão ou não estava em diretório que possuo permissão (algo assim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque:

```
use Ratchet\http\HttpServer;
```

Por:

```
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
```

### Porque isto ocorre:

No Windows os arquivos são case-insentive, quando você roda:

```
use Ratchet\http\HttpServer;
```

Ele encontra no Windows normalmente isto (veja que `Http` começa com a letra `H` em maiúsculo):

```
./src/Ratchet/Http/HttpServer.php
```

Já sistemas Like-unix, como linux usam o sistema de arquivos como case-sensitive, então no momento que você usa `use Ratchet\http\HttpServer;` ele procura isto:

```
./src/Ratchet/http/HttpServer.php
```

Mas no servidor o arquivo esta assim:

```
./src/Ratchet/Http/HttpServer.php
```

São diferentes.

Comment: Show. Uma parte resolveu. Consegui rodar o SSH e não apresentou erro algum.. Porém a conexão ainda não é estabelecida. Após um certo tempo ele volta a apresentar o erro de time out que comentei na questão.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade liberou a porta 8000? Talvez não tenha que rodar via SSH e sim configurar no dashboard, que tipo de servidor usa? Seria o AWS?

Comment: É, não lembro de ter feito nada para liberação da porta não... Você quis dizer qual serviço de hospedagem eu uso? é isso?

Comment: @CelsomTrindade isso, qual serviço de hospedagem, porque dependendo não tem como liberar. Agora se você tiver controle "total", como é no AWS.

Comment: No momento uso www.weblink.com.br

Comment: @CelsomTrindade Nossa :D ... esse servidor é bom? Ele cai muito? O Mysql é estavel? Cara fiquei surpreso contas de email ilimitados... Sobre o seu problema, então aparentemente não tem como rodar um WebSocket, terá que conversas com o suporte pra ter certeza, mas parece que ali não tem esta opção.

Comment: Cara, eu gerencio uma agência de site e hospedo meus clientes ali. Nunca tive nenhuma reclamação, nunca tive problema com suporte, nada do tipo.. Sempre que acessei meus serviços, sempre estiveram online. hahahaha Sobre a questão, já estou em contato com eles para verificar o que pode estar acontecendo, pois ao tentar conexão em 80 ou 443 me da acesso negado e qualquer outra porta da erro de time out.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade Porta 80 e 443 é do Apache, não tem como rodar um socket nelas, elas já estão em uso. Fora que mesmo que inativasse o Apache e roda-se o script ainda sim poderia não funcionar.

Comment: Pois é, são as únicas que retornam algum erro. Todas as demais rodam o script, mas não efetua conexão, sempre aponta o erro. Alguma dica ou sugestão de alternativas?

Comment: Então é como eu disse, Websocket é uma coisa, sites Http é outra, não tem como misturar ambos. Agora existem duas saidas, a primeira é trocar de serviço, mas se ler a doc do Ratchet talvez seja possivel usar sem ser por websocket, veja esse exemplo: http://socketo.me/docs/wamp

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42030/discussion-between-celsomtrindade-and-guilherme-nascimento).